# iPhone - How to implement delegate between my Static library and the app which the library is used?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, delegates, static-libraries

I have been creating a cocoa static library in which I have a public nsobject file where I created a custom delegate. In the app I imported the nsobject file and implemented the delegate but the delegate is not getting called... the static library name is glamApi.

**the SKUIDPasser.h file of the NSObject in the library**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SubClassDelegate  <NSObject>
@required
- (void)MethodNameToCallBack:(NSString *)s;
@end



@interface SKUIDPasser : NSObject

-(void)getSKUIDsFromCart:(NSString *)SKUIDs;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id  <SubClassDelegate> delegatePasser;

@end
```

**and the SKUIDPasser.m file**

```
#import "SKUIDPasser.h"

@implementation SKUIDPasser

@synthesize delegatePasser;

-(void)getSKUIDsFromCart:(NSString *)SKUIDs{

    NSLog(@"getSKUIDsFromCart %@",SKUIDs);

    [delegatePasser MethodNameToCallBack:SKUIDs];

}
@end
```

**And the method is called from a Viewcontroller in static library**

```
- (IBAction)CartShowEvent:(id)sender {
    if (![cartBadge isHidden]) {
        buyClicked = TRUE;

        [self loadCart];
        [self showCartItemsAll];

        self.cartView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:self.cartView];

        SKUIDPasser *pass = [[SKUIDPasser alloc] init];
        [pass getSKUIDsFromCart:@"sssss"];

   } else {
            [Utilities alert:@"No products to display !!!"];
   }
}
```

**The Viewcontroller which the custom delegate has to be implemented Viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <glamAPI/SKUIDPasser.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SubClassDelegate>{
    SKUIDPasser *sk;
}
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sk = [[SKUIDPasser alloc] init];
    sk.delegatePasser = self;

    NSLog(@"sk.delegatePasser %@",sk.delegatePasser);
}

- (void)MethodNameToCallBack:(NSString *)s
{
    NSLog(@"MethodNameToCallBack %@",s);
}
```

I didn't get any error but the method is not calling..Please help me to resolve this

Comment: From where you are calling the method `getSKUIDsFromCart` inside your library OR is it being called explicitly from App Code? Include that code snipped also in your question.

Comment: Hi Gandalf, Thanks for the reply.. actually am calling the method from a view controller in the static library..

Comment: I updated my answer ... see below

Answer (score 0):

The SKUIDPasser object that you are calling within `(IBAction)CartShowEvent:(id)sender` and the SKUIDPasser object that you are setting the delegate are NOT the same.

Just for a test, try calling the method `[sk getSKUIDsFromCart:@"sssss"];` just after you set the delegate and you will see that it will be called because this instance has the delegate set correctly:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sk = [[SKUIDPasser alloc] init];
    sk.delegatePasser = self;
    [sk getSKUIDsFromCart:@"sssss"];

    NSLog(@"sk.delegatePasser %@",sk.delegatePasser);
}

- (void)MethodNameToCallBack:(NSString *)s
{
    NSLog(@"MethodNameToCallBack %@",s);
}
```

**Update**

I updated my answer to help you call the trigger from the static library

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sk = [[SKUIDPasser alloc] init];
    sk.delegatePasser = self;

    /*
    You now can pass this variable to the static library to get called
    from there ... 

    example:
    viewControllerOnStaticLibrary.passer = sk;
    */

    NSLog(@"sk.delegatePasser %@",sk.delegatePasser);
}

- (void)MethodNameToCallBack:(NSString *)s
{
    NSLog(@"MethodNameToCallBack %@",s);
}
```

**Viewcontroller_in_static_library.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKUIDPasser *passer;
```

**Viewcontroller_in_static_library.m**

```
- (IBAction)CartShowEvent:(id)sender {
    if (![cartBadge isHidden]) {
        buyClicked = TRUE;

        [self loadCart];
        [self showCartItemsAll];

        self.cartView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:self.cartView];

        //now you are calling the same instance
        [self.passer getSKUIDsFromCart:@"sssss"];

   } else {
        [Utilities alert:@"No products to display !!!"];
   }
}
```

Comment: Now the delegate get called .... but i want to trigger it from library function..how can i achieve this?..i Understood both are different thanks..

Comment: It depends on how is your project structure or how is the views relations ... has viewcontroller.m direct access to static library?  You can maybe create the object on the viewcontroller.m, pass it to the static library as a parameter and trigger the instance method from there... (instead of creating `SKUIDPasser *pass = [[SKUIDPasser alloc] init];` as you did)

Comment: Can you update your question with your updated code? We are not doing something difficult, and I'm pretty sure we can resolve this problem ...

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you need to understand is that each instance object of a class is entirely different entity and maintains it's state separately.
In you case your have created an object of your static library in `viewDidLoad:` and set the delegate accordingly, but when you are making the call to method getSKUIDsFromCart, you are using a different instance for which you never set the delegate property. That's why there was no callback.

To solve this, you can set the delegate in method `CartShowEvent:` before making the call, something like this

```
SKUIDPasser *pass = [[SKUIDPasser alloc] init];
pass.delegatePasser = self;
[pass getSKUIDsFromCart:@"sssss"];
```

However i would suggest that you should use the instance variable of library which you already created in `viewDidLoad:`

```
- (IBAction)CartShowEvent:(id)sender {
if (![cartBadge isHidden]) {
    buyClicked = TRUE;

    [self loadCart];
    [self showCartItemsAll];

    self.cartView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.cartView];

    //No need to create another object.
    //SKUIDPasser *pass = [[SKUIDPasser alloc] init];

    //Use the previously created instance object
    [sk getSKUIDsFromCart:@"sssss"];

   }
       else {
            [Utilities alert:@"No products to display !!!"];
        }
    }
```